# RewriteRule for tilde

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, tilde

I am trying to do the following rewrite of tilde URLs:

```
RewriteRule ^/?~folder/(.*) http://whatever.com/$1 [R=302,L]
```

I want any links with `whatever.com/~folder/something` to become `whatever.com/something`.

It seems that the above rewrite rule works if my situation excluded the tilde (also tried escaping it, `\~` ), but with the tilde it does not perform the rewrite.

Is there a broader configuration setting I need to adjust to enable rewriting in my situation?  I understand normally `~folder` refers to a user's home directory, but I don't know how that comes into play or can be adjusted in my situation.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix any hits to http://domain.ext/~blog/file.html with this .htaccess rule at webroot (public_html):

```
RewriteRule ^~blog/(.*)$ /site/legacy/users/blog/$1 [R=301,L]
```

From: http://webmaster.iu.edu/tools-and-guides/maintenance/redirect-htaccess.phtml

Answer (score 0):

It is probably linked to the use `mod_userdir`as you mention. Please check in your apache configuration if it is now activated and see if disabling it fixes the issue.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_userdir.html

Answer (score 0):

I use this rule to redirect everything which starts with tilde

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/~([a-z]+)/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.fr/$1 [R=301,L]
```

From @Sigg3.net source : http://webmaster.iu.edu/tools-and-guides/maintenance/redirect-htaccess.phtml